# Image App which does not hide the directory structure

Tags: applications, photos, images

I sync images to the external SD cards of my android5 tablet.

I use this schema:

```
YYYY/MM/DD-event1
YYYY/MM/DD-event2
```

Example:

```
2015/09/01-morning-sunrise
2015/09/01-afternoon-shopping
...
```

All images viewers seem I tried seem to hide the underlying directory structure.

For me it feels like global evil forces trying to keep me stupid.

I can navigate trough the directory structure with the "My Files" app.

Opening a single image works with the gallery or photo app. But swiping to get to the next picture of the directory does not work :-(

How can I navigate the directory and view the images on my external SD card?

Comment: You've used the wrong apps then. My list of [Image Viewers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_galleries#group_200) gives you a bunch of candidates, several of them supporting browsing per folder (e.g. QuickPic, F-Stop).

Comment: I suggest you edit the title. Title is asking for an app which is off-topic here. Body seems fine to me.

Comment: @Firelord the body is asking for an app, too. Why should l change the title?

Comment: Because questions asking us app suggestions/recommendations are off-topic here. See what on-topic in [help/on-topic].

Comment: @Firelord the body of the question is asking for an app. Unfortunately I have not enough reputations to close-vote my own question. Could you please do it? Thank you :-)

Comment: @guettli if you still didn't find what you're looking for, you can try [SR](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185). Also next time you're looking for an app, that's the place to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the X-Plore file manager. It has the exact features of what you have expressed. The other file operations on it are also a lot easier and faster once you get the hang of it. You can read a review before installing from http://reviewlagoon.com/x-plore-file-manager-android/

Answer (score 1):

I use Foto Finder now:

https://github.com/k3b/AndroFotoFinder

Up to now you can't install it via google play, only fdroid :-(

- Can handle big image collections (15000+ images in 1000+ folders).
- Uses Android's image content-provider. No initial image scan neccessary.
- Find images via folder (with hirachical picker), wildcards that match folder/filename,

Comment: Just for the records: since the above app is missing some other features, I use F-Stop now.